# TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/api/get

Tags: python, django

I wanna make a page that shows model's content in json format. 
Now I got an error,
TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/api/get
rest_framework/api.html    .
models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    background_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    h1_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    p_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py is

```
from .models import Color
from rest_framework import serializers


class TaskSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    task_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,source='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Color
        fields = ('name',
                  'background_color',
                  'h1_color',
                  'p_color',
                  'task_name')
```

urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'api/get',views.TaskGet.as_view(),name='task-get')
]
```

views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Color
from .forms import ColorForm
from .serializers import TaskSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from rest_framework import status

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    d = {
        'colors': Color.objects.all(),
        'form': ColorForm(),
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', d)

class TaskGet(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        obj = Color.objects.all()
        serializers = TaskSerializer(obj, many=True)

        return Response(serializers.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I did not write api.html  anywhere.And I did  not regist directory of frest_framework.So,I really cannot understand why this error happens.How can I fix this?

Traceback is

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  72.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in render
  705.         template = loader.get_template(self.template)

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  25.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/api/get/
Exception Value: rest_framework/api.html
```

Comment: include the full error that you are seeing on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make sure that `rest_framework` is listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`:**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework'  # <<<
]
```

---

At first, change your `task-get` url pattern regex like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^api/get/$', views.TaskGet.as_view(), name='task-get')
    # ____^________^___________________
    # Put "begin" and "end" of the url.
]
```

As you want to display all the `Color`s, it's probably a better aproach to use [`ListAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) from **DRF**'s standard library:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class TaskGet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Color.objects.all()
```

As you see, there is no need of implementation of the `get` method, because this is a standard `GET` request and you just need to specify the `queryset` and the `serializer_class` that will be serializing this collection. **DRF** cares for the rest.

This approach will list all your `Color` entries in the database, serialized in JSON format.

Comment: thx ur comments.I wrote ur codes,but same error happens.I updated Traceback in my question,so if u know something please help me.

Comment: @user8504021 Please, make sure that `rest_framework` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

Comment: @user8504021 I've just updated my answer with more detailed solution.

Comment: I did not add rest_framework to my INSTALLED_APPS list,so it did not work.I thought child app should be added in NSTALLED_APPS.So i cannot understand why this solution is fine for my app.

Comment: @user8504021 If you will be using `rest_framework`, you should add it in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and only then you can use it in your apps. See this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation